# Converting a column of strings to numbers in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How do I get the Units column to numeric?

I have a Google spreadsheet that I am reading in the date column gets converted fine.. but I'm not having much luck getting the Unit Sales column to convert to numeric I'm including all the code which uses requests to get the data:

```
from StringIO import StringIO 
import requests
#act = requests.get('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ak_wF7ZGeMmHdFZtQjI1a1hhUWR2UExCa2E4MFhiWWc&output=csv&gid=1')
dataact = act.content
actdf = pd.read_csv(StringIO(dataact),index_col=0,parse_dates=['date'])
actdf.rename(columns={'Unit Sales': 'Units'}, inplace=True) #incase the space in the name is messing me up
```

The different methods I have tried to get Units to get to numeric

```
actdf=actdf['Units'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
#actdf=actdf['Units'].astype('float32')
```

Then I want to resample and I'm getting strange string concatenations since the numbers are still string

```
#actdfq=actdf.resample('Q',sum)
#actdfq.head()
actdf.head()
#actdf
```

so the df looks like this with just units and the date index

```
date
2013-09-01    3,533
2013-08-01    4,226
2013-07-01    4,281
Name: Units, Length: 161, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify the thousands separator:

```
actdf = pd.read_csv(StringIO(dataact), index_col=0, parse_dates=['date'], thousands=',')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
This will work

In [13]: s
Out[13]: 
0    4,223
1    3,123
dtype: object

In [14]: s.str.replace(',','').convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
Out[14]: 
0    4223
1    3123
dtype: int64
```